# How do I update an embedded document based on its id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an embedded document that needs to be updated. I am having trouble figuring out how to update the document given the id. Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
var Post = require('../models/post');
var comment_id = 5394f5be2f6953083908db47;
var updateData = {
    comment: req.body.comment,
    title: req.body.title
};

Post.update({ comments : { _id : comment_id } }, updateData, function(err,data) {
    return res.json({success: true});
});

var postCommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    comment : String,
    user : String,
    tags : [],
    created : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    post : String,
    title : String,
    created : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    comments : [postCommentSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', postSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "comment_id" variable needs to be quoted to be valid JavaScript. But basically as this is a singular `_id` value that cannot appear more than once you can use "dot notation" to address the required field. Then you need a [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator to reference the index of the field that you matched in the update side.

Also you need the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator otherwise your "updateData" object is going to overwrite the existing data in your array member you are referencing, namely the date which is missing here:

```
var comment_id = "5394f5be2f6953083908db47";

Post.update(
    { "comments._id" : comment_id } }, 
    { "$set": { 
        "comments.$.comment": req.body.comments,
        "comments.$.title": req.body.title
    } }, 
    function(err,numAffected) {
       return res.json({success: true});
    }
);
```

Though you are not using it here, the second argument to the callback for [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) is the number of documents affected by the statement and not the actual document or data. To get the document back as a result, look at methods such as [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) in the mongoose API documentation.

Also the official MongoDB documentation for [`.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) shows several common usage cases.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but there are still some issues. You suggested using ``$set`` so my existing data isn't overwritten. However, the way it is now, all fields that are not included in the ``updateData`` object are deleted from the document when I attempt an update. How can I modify your code so existing "fields" are not deleted?

Comment: @ChrisPaterson You are right. I was two busy pointing out the other parts that I forgot to correct that. Altered in the answer. Basically also "dot notation" with the use of the positional operator.